# Bootstrap Drop-down Menu not working in Navbar

Tags: html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I've been learning some bootstrap and have moved onto navbars, I've created my navbar and when the screen is made smaller my nav mar moves into a "sandwich" drop down menu that you often see on a phone except it doesn't work when clicked and I have no idea why, I've received no errors at all ! Any ideas ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>BootStrap Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
    BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style>
   .thumb{padding: 60px 10px; text-align: center; background: #fff;}
   .thumb:nth-child(even){background: #fff;}
   h1, h2{margin: 30px 0;}
   .contatiner-fluid, .container{}
   .thumb:nth-child(odd){clear: both;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

  <div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="/indx.html" class="navbar-brand">AWESOME TRAINING</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
   </div>

   <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Ninja Training</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Wizard Training</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Phsycic Training</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Coding Training</a></li>
     </ul>

    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right" style="margin-left: 10px;">Register</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Log In</button>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
   </div>

  </div>

 </nav>

 <div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>Navbars</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
       in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
       sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"</script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
  Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script>
   $(".nav li").on("click", function(){
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

   });
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nothing major you forget to close the script tag. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing major, you just missed the closing tag ">"after jquery src URL. Check out the jQuery Script starts tag and after URL end tag.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>BootStrap Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
    BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style>
   .thumb{padding: 60px 10px; text-align: center; background: #fff;}
   .thumb:nth-child(even){background: #fff;}
   h1, h2{margin: 30px 0;}
   .contatiner-fluid, .container{}
   .thumb:nth-child(odd){clear: both;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

  <div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="/indx.html" class="navbar-brand">AWESOME TRAINING</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
   </div>

   <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Ninja Training</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Wizard Training</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Phsycic Training</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Coding Training</a></li>
     </ul>

    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right" style="margin-left: 10px;">Register</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Log In</button>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
   </div>

  </div>

 </nav>

 <div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>Navbars</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
       in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
       sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
  Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script>
   $(".nav li").on("click", function(){
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

   });
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! Couldn't see that at all!

Comment: @DannyOReilly no problem mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery and the jQuery bootstrap plugins file:

jQuery:

`<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Bootstrap JS:

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

> Requires JavaScript plugin
>   If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse. The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

[From Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>BootStrap Site</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
       BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
      .thumb{padding: 60px 10px; text-align: center; background: #fff;}
      .thumb:nth-child(even){background: #fff;}
      h1, h2{margin: 30px 0;}
      .contatiner-fluid, .container{}
      .thumb:nth-child(odd){clear: both;}
  </style>
</head>

     <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

         <div class="container-fluid">

           <div class="navbar-header">
             <a href="/indx.html" class="navbar-brand">AWESOME TRAINING</a>
             <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
           </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="#">Ninja Training</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Wizard Training</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Phsycic Training</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Coding Training</a></li>
         </ul>

            <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right" style="margin-left: 10px;">Register</button>
           <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Log In</button>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          </div>

       </div>

  </nav>

                <div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px;">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1>Navbars</h1>
                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                           in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                           sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <script>
              $(".nav li").on("click", function(){
                $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");

              });
          </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"</script>
```

You was omit `>` char and jquery doesn't load. Working code below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```